# Control flow between two for each loops

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

Hey guys id appreciate any wisdom you guys can bestow onto me.

My problem is: I can't get it to cycle through the two arrays
       so i can compare the elements of each array and get a result.

I have tried removing the break but it still doesn't cycle though the first 
    array, it just keeps cycling through the second and printing it
    sorry if its been asked I couldn't find what I was looking for.

```java
    outerloop:
    for(int i=1;i<7;i++){

        System.out.print("Round No: " + i + "-");      

        for(int x : Player1)  {
            for(int y : Player2) {  

                if (x < y) {
                    System.out.println(" Player 1 wins the round: " + x + " beats " + y);
                } else if (x > y) {
                    System.out.println(" Player 2 wins the round: " + y + " beats " + x);  
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Tie!" + x + " ties with " + y);
                    break outerloop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The result i get from this is it just cycles through the first array once
    and cycles and compares everything in the second

I am trying to get it to do both simultaneously.
.......................................................................................................................
..............................

Comment: A few questions: What are Player1 and Player2? Do you know that they always have the same number of elements? Can you access their elements by index i.e. Player1.get(0) or something similar? Are you expecting to break out of the whole loop when you see a tie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea, if you have got the same number of elements in your player 1 and 2 objects, why not put them in separate arrays and then work with the incidences of just one of them? As in the following example:

```java
List<Integer> p1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> p2 = new ArrayList<>();

for(int x: Player1) {
   p1.add(x);
}

for(int y: Player2) {
   p2.add(y);
}

for(int i=0;i<p1.size(); i++) {
    x = p1.get(i);
    y = p2.get(i);
    if (x < y) {
        System.out.println(" Player 1 wins the round: " + x + " beats " + y);
    } else if (x > y) {
        System.out.println(" Player 2 wins the round: " + y + " beats " + x);  
    } else {
        System.out.println("Tie!" + x + " ties with " + y);
    }
}
```